# Is it possible to change default value of all table using SQL procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to change the default value of sql table fields from 'none' to 'null' where the datatypes are char varchar longtext etc. And I want to keep the default value if its not 'none'. And there are more than 500 tables I need to alter. Is there any way to do so? And should I use PL? Is there any other methods to do so?Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a question. It's a statement. You need to change something. Fine. Why did you post it as a question?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This isn't a free code-writing service, you need to have shown at least some evidence of having researched and tried to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is:

```
ALTER TABLE 'tablename' ALTER COLUMN 'columnname' SET DEFAULT 'none'
```

First I selected all tables from database using this query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM 'database'";
```

And selected all columns using a loop:

```
mysql_fetch_field
```

Then I run the code: And it worked .Thank you every one who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to update the none to `NULL` and the column is of type `varchar`

```
 update table_name set column = null where column = 'none';
```

you need to update schema of table as well, need to set the default value as NULL using alteration.

Comment: Note that this will not make the difference between default values and value that was set as `none` during input. But there is no way to do that difference (not that I know at least)

Comment: I updated my answer, need to update schema as well for default value as null. @AxelH

Comment: Indeed, but that's not what I meant. Just pointing the fact that there is not way to see the difference between a row with a default value (no value set ) and a `none` value gave by the user.

Comment: `'none'` seems to be a default CUSTOM value that's inserted when user adds no value..we can add custom default value in schema and `none` is a custom default value while `(no value set )` is the default representation.

Comment: I know that, but you don't seems to understand (might be my bad english...) Here is an example : `insert into table_name(column) values( 'none')` and `insert into table_name(column) values( null )` will gave the same row ('none'), but one was specified by the user as what he wants, the other is the default value. Your query will update both to `null`, removing the value specified by the user. That's the warning I am pointing. Off course there is no other solution but this should be mention that there is a risk to update values that is not really default but is the same as default.

Comment: agreed on what you say but not sure why would a user add value `none`, can be a case though.

Comment: Because the question is not that specific "_Is it possible to change default value of all table using SQL procedure?_"! So if a future user have a similar problem with a default value that could have more sense to be inputted as a value, this could have unwanted result.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me guys. But this is not the answer I am looking for. I want to change the default values of n number of tables from "none" to "null" with single procedure.